# Start with RxJava, loop

Tags: java, android, rx-java

Can someone tell me how can I change default code of java like that:

```
   private ArrayList<RateItem> generateRates(List<Rates> ratesList){
    rateItemArrayList=new ArrayList<RateItem>();

    for(Rates rates : ratesList)
        rateItemArrayList.add(new RateItem(rates.getName(),rates.getCode(),rates.getValue()));

    return rateItemArrayList;
}
```

to code in RxJava? Im just starting and i cant handle the basics yet : (

**EDIT**

I  have no idea why this loop iterating more times than my List from response has. Then my new Arraylist has 1300 items instead of 30. What is wrong?

```
 private Observable<ArrayList<RateItem>> generateRates(List<Rates> rates){
    rateItemArrayList = new ArrayList<RateItem>();

    Observable<ArrayList<RateItem>> observable = Observable.from(rates)
            .map(new Func1<Rates, ArrayList<RateItem>>() {
                @Override
                public ArrayList<RateItem> call(Rates rat) {
                    for(Rates ratt : rates)
                        rateItemArrayList.add(new RateItem(ratt.getName(),ratt.getCode(),ratt.getValue()));
                    return rateItemArrayList;
                }
            });

    return observable;
}
```

@Weava 
I dont know but I cant make your code, AS automatically generates code like above.

Comment: something like `Observable.from(ratesList).map(rates -> new RateItem(rates.getName(),rates.getCode(),rates.getValue())).subscribe(<your callback here>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `RxJava` you might do something like this, using the `from` and `map` functions.

```
private Observable<List<RateItem>> generateRates(List<Rates> ratesList) {
    Observable<List<RateItem>> myObservable = Observable.from(ratesList)
            .map(new Func1<List<Rates>, List<RateItem>>() {

                @Override
                public List<RateItem> call(List<Rates> rateList) {
                    List<RateItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

                    for(Rates rates : ratesList) {
                        items.add(new RateItem(rates.getName(), rates.getCode(), rates.getValue()));
                    }
                    return items;
                }
            });

      return myObservable;
}
```

In this function, I am adding the `ratesList` object to be emitted by the observable. Then, as the list is being emitted, I map it to the `List<RateItem>` objects. Then I just return the `Observable` for subscription wherever I call this method.

If you are using RetroLamda, you could definitely make this look a little nicer (see @njzk2's comment) but I wanted to show what was actually going on.

As an example of how to subscribe to your new Observalbe, it would looks something like this:

```
    generateRates(new ArrayList<Rates>()).subscribe(new Func1<List<RateItem>>(){
        @Override
        public void call(List<RateItem> rateItems) {
            // Do whatever it is you need to do with your list
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can directly iterate through the given list, no need to map the entire List again... See @Tassos answer

Comment: @Khuzy Check out Retrolamda if you haven't already. It's great, and allows you to do things like Tassos answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
private Observable<RateItem> generateRates(List<Rates> ratesList){
   return Observable
     .from(ratesList)
     .map(rates -> new RateItem(rates.getName(),rates.getCode(),rates.getValue());
}
```

Actually, I would even skip having `List<anything>` for actual usage (not inter-module APIs, but intra-module coordination), in which case the whole method becomes a simple call:

```
.map(rates -> new RateItem(rates.getName(),rates.getCode(),rates.getValue());
```

In fact, I'd say just refactor out the constructor into a separate static method in RateItem, preferably a constructor, then it's just

```
.map(RateItem::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code, I think this can work, but I didn't test it. Hope this can help you to start with `RxJava`:

```
List<Rates> ratesList;
List rateItemArrayList = new ArrayList<RateItem>();
Observable.just(ratesList)
        .flatMap(new Func1<List<Rates>, Observable<RateItem>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<RateItem> call(List<Rates> rate) {
                return Observable.just(new RateItem(rate.getName(), rate.getCode(), rate.getValue()));
            }
        }).subscribe(new Action1<RateItem>() {
    @Override
    public void call(RateItem rateItem) {
        rateItemArrayList.add(rateItem);
    }
});
```

Comment: I would advise against using flat maps as you are not trying to map an item into multiple observables, then emit as one He is just trying to map the objects from a `List<Rate>` to `List<RateItem>` and emit as one item through the observable. Just a regular map function should do in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, I´ve create this unit test

```
class RateItem {
    String name;
    String code;

    public RateItem(String name, String code) {
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
    }
}

class Rate {
    String name;
    String code;

    public Rate(String name, String code) {
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
    }
}

@Test
public void migrateToObservable() {
    generateRates(Arrays.asList(new Rate("a", "1"), new Rate("b", "2")));
}

private List<RateItem> generateRates(List<Rate> ratesList) {
    return  Observable.from(ratesList)
            .map(rate-> new RateItem(rate.name, rate.code))
            .toList().toBlocking().first();
}
```

If you want to see some RXJava examples take a look here https://github.com/politrons/reactive

Answer (score 0):

Another way without a lot of changes is using `Observable.defer(generateRates());` this will transform your old code into Observable.